# lxc-clone not working with overlayfs in centos 7

Tags: linux, overlay, lxc, centos7

I have created a container say base and I am trying to create a clone of the base container with backing store as overlayfs. But it always fails with the following error,

```
lxc_container: bdev.c: overlayfs_mount: 2237 No such device - overlayfs: error mounting /var/lib/lxc/base/rootfs onto /usr/lib64/lxc/rootfs options upperdir=/var/lib/lxc/s0/delta0,lowerdir=/var/lib/lxc/base/rootfs,workdir=/var/lib/lxc/s0/olwork
clone failed
```

Any way to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Vishnu Ganth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as if they `overlay` filesystem is not available in your kernel.  First, check if it is listed in `/proc/filesystems`:

```
# grep overlay /proc/filesystems
nodev   overlay
```

If it's not there, it may be available as a loadable kernel module.  You can load it using `modprobe`:

```
# modprobe overlay
```

If this resolves your issue, you'll want to configure your system to automatically load this module when it boots.  On a systemd-based system, you can create `/etc/modules-load.d/overlay.conf` with the content:

```
overlay
```

And you're done.  For non-systemd based distributions, consult the appropriate documentation.

**Update**

The name of the `overlay` filesystem changed from `overlayfs` to `overlay` at some point.  Support for this was added in commit [38b3491](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/commit/38b34913fad2a4bcc842c2c377c0cb7bb90abe0f), which was made *after* the release of lxc 1.0.7.  It looks like this change should be available in LXC releases 1.1.1 and later.

The `lxc` package on CentOS comes from the EPEL repository.  You should probably open a bug report against the package ([here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Fedora%20EPEL)) reporting the problem; it should be reasonably easy for the package maintainer to fix this for EPEL7.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the contents to overlay.conf and now I can see overlay content in /proc/filesystems. But still I am getting the above mentioned error when I try lxc-clone

Comment: What distribution are you using, and what version of lxc?

Comment: Am using CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 and lxc-1.0.7-1.el7.x86_64

Comment: See my update regarding the LXC version available on CentOS 7.